# 32bit float image format getpixel?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, hdr

How would I use 32bit float images with C#?

I would prefer to use openExr but, tiff or similar would be fine as well, basically I just want to load an 32bit float *(32bit per pixel / channel)* image from disk and get the pixel values of a single channel and put that in an array, preferably as simple as solution as possible.

**This is a simple test example I made that works with png:**
[image]

**[Download visual studio project](http://patan77.com/download/ImageToArray.zip)**

**Code: C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ImgToVxlForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        Byte[] byteArr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                dlg.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    myBitmap = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;
                }
            }
        }

        private void runBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byteArr = (ImageToArr(myBitmap));
            for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Debug.WriteLine(byteArr[i]);
            }
            lb_debug.Text = byteArr.Length.ToString();
        }

        public static byte[] ImageToArr(Bitmap inBitmap)
        {
            int w = inBitmap.Width;
            int h = inBitmap.Height;
            Byte[] tmpByteArr = new byte[w * h];
            int count = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = inBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    tmpByteArr[count] = pixelColor.R;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return tmpByteArr;
        }
    }
}
```

**[Download 16 and 32bit test tiff image: (19KB)](http://www.patan77.com/download/16_32bit_tiff_test.zip)**

Comment: So what is the code you've included? Does it not work?

Comment: my code works for 8bit images (png currently) but I want a to use 32bit float images like tiff or  openExr

Comment: Look for code examples for DICOM.  Images such as JPEG2000 support HDR 12 bit+ grayscale for example

Comment: Also, _"...get the pixel values of a single channel..."_ - I don't think you understand high dynamic range (HDR) _"32 bit float"_ images.  You don't just get a pixel color.  A single file represents a multitude of exposures so getting the pixel color would be a funtion of your _window level_.  You **can't** just `inBitmap.GetPixel(x,y)`

Comment: Umm, think you the one that don't understand  HDR 32bit float images... If you make an HDR image with photography you merge multiple exposures, the 32bit float image is just 32bit float values per channel, a 8bit 0-255 would be 0.0-1.0 in float and you can have values that are negative and far beyond  as well, the thing is I have already written the application with MaxScript .Net and it support getPixels(x,y) 32bit float OpenEXR out of the box, and I'm just trying to translate that application to a standalone C# application.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the System.Drawing package, which is based on the GDI+ Win32 APIs. Per the ImageCodecInfo class documentation, you'll see that it has, built-in, support for several types:

> Image encoders are built into GDI+ for the BMP, JPEG, GIF, TIFF, and
>   PNG formats.

In theory, using a TIFF image should just work. If you need to add support for other decoders, you can either find a package that does that specifically and either use the package's native types or write a wrapper that generates a Bitmap object for you to consume, or you can use a more extensible API, e.g. the Windows Imaging Component.

As you are in .NET-land, there's a pretty good DirectX (and associated technologies, including WIC) wrapper called [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). Here's a [GitHub sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/OfflineImageProcessingApp/Program.cs) that shows off how to do this. The caveat here is that it's a lower-level API that System.Drawing and requires more boilerplate code to bring online, as well as exposing COM to you directly; the benefit is that any WIC-compatible codec available on your system can be used, and you can use the same APIs to enumerate which formats are supported.

Comment: well currently it works with 16bit tif as well (just change the filter on browse) but not 32bit tif just gets error if i try.

16 and 32bit tiff test images:
http://www.patan77.com/download/16_32bit_tiff_test.zip

Comment: Might look into how  to use WIC, considering it looks to kind of do what I'm  trying to do, Found http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html so gonna look in to that as well, I just kind of want a simple quick and dirty solution for now, because still gonna have to  replace it in the future.

Comment: TIFF images are natively supported by `System.Drawing`. OpenEXR is not, `SharpEXR` can be added in and then utilized within your code. Or you could add in some OpenEXR codec and play with Windows Imaging. Either way seems to preclude the _simple quick and dirty_

Comment: For quick and dirty you can try using a TIFF library directly; there's a .NET implementation of LibTiff in the form of a .NET Standard Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/

Comment: Decoding a HDR image is one thing, displaying is another which you don't really go into and that is where you run into major technical problems.   Just using DirectX sadly doesn't display HDR images either.  The choice of TIFF library is irrelevant